# Forbid javascript in a div

Tags: javascript, html, web

At the moment I am working on a website. Inside this website administrators shall be able to post text.

I´d like to give the user a possibility to use HTML-Code, but I do not want them to be able to post javascript code.

Is there an html-Tag (or workaround) to prohibit javascript?

Comment: Sounds like it would be safer to use markdown instead of html.

Comment: Use regex to strip any and all `<script class="don't forget about props">content here</script>`

Comment: I think Regex it's what you want:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052486/5062956](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052486/5062956)

Comment: What's on backend? More details required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find "<script>" tag from the string with JAVASCRIPT/ regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585635/how-to-find-script-tag-from-the-string-with-javascript-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no plain html tag that blocks inline JS from running.

Between the many workarounds, the most elegant one is to disable inline script tags altogether by using CSP headers, but this may not be possible depending on your current architecture. You could also consider using some sanitization library to clean up the post content, there are simple strategies like using a regex to find `<script` tags.

I suggest reading https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/ to get a better sense of how CSP works and what are your options.

It's also worth reading https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet